# Getting UTF-32 error when getting Facebook post

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

Looks like the FacebookClient.Get("path") method is returning an error for invalid UTF-32 characters in some Facebook posts.

Here is the code and the specific post that creates the problem:

```
string token = "yourtokenhere";
FacebookClient client = new FacebookClient(token);
dynamic result = client.Get("203621737645_147058518666707");
```

This is returning the following error:
Error:A valid UTF32 value is between 0x000000 and 0x10ffff, inclusive, and should not include surrogate codepoint values (0x00d800 ~ 0x00dfff).

What to do with this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed since v5.0.46. Make sure to update to the lastest Facebook C# SDK.